# Express Server Responds to POST Request Before Recieving the Body

Tags: node.js, express, post

I have an express server that I created using *express-generator*, and setup by following one of the thousands of available online tutorials. As far as express servers go, it's fairly unremarkable. When I send POST request from Postman, or from my React app, it takes the body and stuffs it into the database, then sends the response, exactly as I expect.
The problem occurs when I try to send it a POST request from a microcontroller via a 4G modem using AT commands. This is considerably slower than a browser, and involves a delay of several milliseconds between the header and the body. During this delay, instead of waiting for the POST body, the server goes ahead and sends the response as though the body was empty.

At first, the problem appeared to be with the modem or the firmware, but I was able to narrow it down to the server by making POST requests to a different server. I made a POST to the *dweet.io* API, and observed that after the modem transmitted the header, it sat for a few seconds to allow the microcontroller to upload the body.

It feels like this has something to do with a timeout setting in express, but the only thing I could find in that department is *server.timeout*, which I have verified to be 120000. Is there any setting or middleware I could use to force the server to chill out and wait for the body?